# Add Publishing options to custom entity

Tags: entities

How do you add publishing options to a custom entity or it's bundles? 
Currently when I create a new Entity entry I only have a save option. I would like to add published and unpublished states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 8.3 there is now an interface for this:

> Content entities that need a published/unpublished flag base field are
>   now able to declare a "published" entity key in their entity type
>   annotation. Such entities should implement the new
>   \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityPublishedInterface and use the
>   \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityPublishedTrait trait. The interface can be
>   implemented directly, by the entity class, or by the entity
>   specialised interface.
>
> ```
> use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityPublishedInterface;
> use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityPublishedTrait;
> use ...
>
> /**
>  * @ContentEntityType(
>  *   id = "custom_entity",
>  *   ...
>  *   entity_keys = {
>  *     "id" = "id",
>  *     "published" = "status",
>  *     "label" = "label",
>  *   },
>  *   ...
>  * )
>  */
> class CustomEntity extends ContentEntityBase implements CustomEntityInterface, EntityPublishedInterface {
>   use EntityPublishedTrait;
>    ...
> }
> ```
>
> Entities defined in this way can benefit of the new provided methods
>   to set the published status ON/OFF and are able to inspect the status
>   of the published flag field:
>
> ```
> $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('custom_entity');
> $entity = $storage->load(123);
>
> // Reverse the published status.
> if ($entity->isPublished()) {
>   $entity->setUnpublished();
> }
> else {
>   $entity->setPublished();
> }
>
> $entity->save()
> ```

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/2830201

If you are developing for 8.4 you can use the base class

> **EditorialContentEntityBase - a new base entity class for revisionable and publishable entity types**
>
> Drupal 8.4.0 increases its usage of the revisioning and publishing
>   features from Entity API by converting some if its most widely used
>   content entity types: Taxonomy terms, Menu links, Comments, etc.
>
> In order to reduce code duplication and boilerplate, a new content
>   entity base class is now available for entity types that want to
>   support those features by default: EditorialContentEntityBase.
>
> If you are defining a content entity type in a contributed module or
>   in your project's custom code, it is recommended to extend the
>   \Drupal\Core\Entity\EditorialContentEntityBase base class in order to
>   get out-of-the-box support for Entity API's revisioning and publishing
>   features, which will allow your entity type to be used with Drupal's
>   editorial workflow provided by the Content Moderation module.

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/2870643